# Can I install MS OFFICE 2013 (Genuine Version) inside Wine in Lubuntu 14.10?

Tags: lubuntu, wine

I have a genuine version of MS OFFICE 2013 as .exe format. Can I install and execute it as a full program inside the wine in lubuntu 14.10? Without installing Windows in my computer.

Comment: Do you need _instructions_ on how to install a program in Wine, or are you having _issues_ when trying to install?

Comment: Yes, Obviously. I need the step by step instructions on how to install a program in Wine.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please accept it to close this question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Once you've installed Wine (available in the Software Centre), these are the steps you need to follow to install a program in Wine.

1. Locate the installation .exe
2. Right click on the .exe and choose 'Properties'
3. Tick the box: 'Allow executing file as program'
4. Now double click the .exe to open it as you would a normal program
5. Follow the installation instructions the way you would on Windows

Hope I helped :)

Source: [How to Install Windows Programs in Ubuntu - WikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Windows-Programs-in-Ubuntu)

Comment: Yes .... At last MS OFFICE 2013 worked in Lubuntu 14.10 with the help of wine software without any issues .... Your step-by-step instructions helped me very much and now you can close this question forever .... 

Thanks buddy

Comment: @KannanSoorej Hi, I'd really appreciate it if you marked my answer as accepted (just click the little tick next to my answer). This will help other people with the same problem to find my solution. Thanks :)